# Объеденить 2 массива в map

Tags: map, c++11

Всем доброго времени! Возникла проблема, начал писать функцию для объеденения 2 string и double массива в один map.

```
    map<string, double> toMap(const string* str,double* params){
    map<string, double> rMap;
    //как узнать колличество элементов массиве str или params?

    return rMap;
}
toMap(new string[3]{"name1","name2","name4"}, new double[3]{1,2,3});
```

Методы типо sizeof и др непомагают. Есть другие способы решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. чтобы знать размер нужно хранить
       string и double в vector или array
       (вызывая метод size() получаем
       размер)
2. у вас утечка памяти, где удаляется 
       `string[3]` и `double[3]` ?

**а зачем 2 массива запихивать в один map?**

Comment: Спасибо, с вектором все получилось. Думаю мне стоит лучше изучить стандартные типы в c++

Comment: это не типы! это контейнеры данных! или структуры данных! (на мой взгляд большая разница!)

для начала узнай :

 1. что такое **О** нотация (сложность
    алгоритмов)
 2. какие структуры данных (контейнеры)
    бывают и чем они отличаются

p.s. вот только краткий список структур данных: массив,вектор, списки-очереди(однонаправленные(LIFO,FIFO), двунаправленные, замкнутые), умные указатели, деревья(бинарные, суффиксные, самобалансирующиеся(red-black,avl)), сеты, мапы, буферы...

Answer (score 0):

А вектор никак тут нельзя использовать?

Или используйте еще один параметр для передачи их кол-ва.

И вообще ваш код ужасен...

Comment: Я плохо разбираюсь в c++, уж прошу прощения за это, но как можно еще передать массивы в функцию чтобы с ними можно было нормально работать? И еще чем вектор лучше обычного map?

Comment: Блин, это полный привет...

Тапочки лучше ботинок? Ну ты и спросил...

В общем тебе @ProkletyiPirat все написал.

Comment: Мне кажется вам лучше с литературы надо начать, а там все дальше по накатанной пойдет, а то уж очень поверхностные знания о стандартных контейнерах.